# Boolean value isn't working properly in C Programming Language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, primes, function-definition

I tried to make a prime number generator but I don't know why it's not working. Because according to the code, it should work fine. I used a if statement somewhere in the functions and I think it's getting a false value every time when it should get a true value. It should give me all the prime numbers until the user provided value but it gives me nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool isPrime(int num) {
    int sqroot = (int)sqrt((double)num);
    for (int i = 1; i <= sqroot; i++){
        if (num%i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
void gen(int num){
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            counter++;
            printf("%d : %d\n", counter, i);
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    gen(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do  you know it's not working?

Comment: If it is the `isPrime` function that is not working you don't need to include `gen` function. Please fix a [mre]

Comment: @klutt: isPrime is called by the gen function, and the code is small enough already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Creating a mre is an important part of learning how to debug. But nevertheless, OP has not stated expected and actual behavior for a certain input.

Comment: The expected behavior is that the program should print out all of the prime numbers up to the number that is inputted by the user.

Comment: What is any number mod 1?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The solution is already lurking in the comments, and the general advice to debug is good. Specifically, if you run your program under a debugger and single-step through for a sufficiently small value (say, 3), it won't take long to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop starts at `i = 1` and hence the test `(num % i == 0)` always evaluates to `true` at the first iteration. Just start with `i = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `isPrime` is wrong. Each number is divisible by `1`. So the function always will return `false`.

Also the function parameter should have an unsigned integer type instead of the signed integer type `int`. It is better to declare it as having the type  `unsigned long long`.

You could declare the function like

```
bool isPrime( unsigned long long n );
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
bool isPrime( unsigned long long n )
{
    bool prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

    for ( unsigned long long i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Your program can be written the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime( unsigned long long n )
{
    bool prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

    for ( unsigned long long i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}

void gen( unsigned long long n )
{
    size_t count = 0;
    
    for ( unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( isPrime( i + 1 ) )
        {
            printf( "%zu : %llu\n", ++count, i + 1 );
        }           
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned long long n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%llu", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        gen( n );
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2
1 : 2

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 100
1 : 2
2 : 3
3 : 5
4 : 7
5 : 11
6 : 13
7 : 17
8 : 19
9 : 23
10 : 29
11 : 31
12 : 37
13 : 41
14 : 43
15 : 47
16 : 53
17 : 59
18 : 61
19 : 67
20 : 71
21 : 73
22 : 79
23 : 83
24 : 89
25 : 97

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```